# How to Correctly merge 2 JSONs

Tags: c#, json.net

I have 2 JSONs that I get from separate API calls.

Here is first one:

```json
{
   [
      {
         "name":"job a",
         "instanceUid":"c083aa59-b362-400b-a4e1-245ce707d3a9",
         "type":"BackupCopy",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2020-10-20T11:53:10.183-04:00"
      },
      {
         "name":"job b",
         "instanceUid":"b65d3326-1878-4a4b-858c-522806da172f",
         "type":"BackupCopy",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":null
      },
      {
         "name":"job c",
         "instanceUid":"02bef7df-08a8-4d75-a50e-3dc7e8dd9edb",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Failed",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T17:40:09.23-05:00"
      },
      {
         "name":"job d",
         "instanceUid":"f1848f1f-962d-49ba-a0b0-cac9c1d5746a",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2020-08-11T13:52:09.987-04:00"
      },
      {
         "name":"job e",
         "instanceUid":"e2ac93da-3028-4501-91bd-1e25255651eb",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T16:00:22.733-05:00"
      },
      {
         "name":"job f",
         "instanceUid":"db81e5c5-4e6f-4160-bced-f26f85a6cea2",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-25T13:00:01.663-05:00"
      },
      {
         "name":"job g",
         "instanceUid":"bd45a460-1af3-4bfe-aa07-02b959487bdd",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T17:00:03.253-05:00"
      },
      {
         "name":"job h",
         "instanceUid":"a4f5c4d8-c84b-4efd-91f0-cf8429604d6f",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T17:00:04.393-05:00"
      },
      {
         "name":"job i",
         "instanceUid":"9623dda4-8d8d-45b5-aa8a-b59feb828178",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Failed",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T17:30:54.88-05:00"
      },
      {
         "name":"job j",
         "instanceUid":"8e8319d6-a03e-4926-969f-c38f060b2bb1",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T17:00:03.643-05:00"
      },
      {
         "name":"job k",
         "instanceUid":"79840a7e-b4b1-4284-ba20-de4eef1ada3f",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Failed",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T17:30:54.893-05:00"
      },
      {
         "name":"job l",
         "instanceUid":"32e5569f-3d7c-4bff-9fbf-cf00a9efddcf",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T17:00:04.02-05:00"
      },
      {
         "name":"job m",
         "instanceUid":"1230f103-38ce-405b-88c6-6f5c0cd62119",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T21:00:19.123-05:00"
      }
   ]
}
```

The second one:

```json
{
   [
      {
         "instanceUid":"02bef7df-08a8-4d75-a50e-3dc7e8dd9edb",
         "protectedVmCount":0
      },
      {
         "instanceUid":"f1848f1f-962d-49ba-a0b0-cac9c1d5746a",
         "protectedVmCount":1
      },
      {
         "instanceUid":"e2ac93da-3028-4501-91bd-1e25255651eb",
         "protectedVmCount":1
      },
      {
         "instanceUid":"db81e5c5-4e6f-4160-bced-f26f85a6cea2",
         "protectedVmCount":0
      },
      {
         "instanceUid":"bd45a460-1af3-4bfe-aa07-02b959487bdd",
         "protectedVmCount":1
      },
      {
         "instanceUid":"a4f5c4d8-c84b-4efd-91f0-cf8429604d6f",
         "protectedVmCount":1
      },
      {
         "instanceUid":"9623dda4-8d8d-45b5-aa8a-b59feb828178",
         "protectedVmCount":1
      },
      {
         "instanceUid":"8e8319d6-a03e-4926-969f-c38f060b2bb1",
         "protectedVmCount":1
      },
      {
         "instanceUid":"79840a7e-b4b1-4284-ba20-de4eef1ada3f",
         "protectedVmCount":1
      },
      {
         "instanceUid":"32e5569f-3d7c-4bff-9fbf-cf00a9efddcf",
         "protectedVmCount":2
      },
      {
         "instanceUid":"1230f103-38ce-405b-88c6-6f5c0cd62119",
         "protectedVmCount":1
      }
   ]
}
```

I use the following C# code using the Newtonsoft JSON library to try to merge the 2 and trying to base it on the `instanceUid` as the key.  (I did `SelectToken` because the orginal json has a metadata section that I don't need.)

```cs
var a = (JArray)organizationResponse.SelectToken("data");
var b = (JArray)protectedVms.SelectToken("data");

a.Merge(b, new JsonMergeSettings
{
    MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Merge
    
});
```

But I get the following result back.  Some of the `instanceUid` are placed wrong and the last 2 jobs j and k don't have the `protectedVMCount` property.  The Newtonsoft documentation mentions that the MergeArrayHandling.Merge merges based on index, but they don't provide an example on this 'index'.    Does anybody know how to do it or is there an alternative way?  Basically I'm trying to do a merge based on the `instanceUid`.  Thanks.

```json
{
   [
      {
         "name":"job a",
         "instanceUid":"02bef7df-08a8-4d75-a50e-3dc7e8dd9edb",
         "type":"BackupCopy",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2020-10-20T11:53:10.183-04:00",
         "protectedVmCount":0
      },
      {
         "name":"job b",
         "instanceUid":"f1848f1f-962d-49ba-a0b0-cac9c1d5746a",
         "type":"BackupCopy",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":null,
         "protectedVmCount":1
      },
      {
         "name":"job c",
         "instanceUid":"e2ac93da-3028-4501-91bd-1e25255651eb",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Failed",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T17:40:09.23-05:00",
         "protectedVmCount":1
      },
      {
         "name":"job d",
         "instanceUid":"db81e5c5-4e6f-4160-bced-f26f85a6cea2",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2020-08-11T13:52:09.987-04:00",
         "protectedVmCount":0
      },
      {
         "name":"job e",
         "instanceUid":"bd45a460-1af3-4bfe-aa07-02b959487bdd",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T16:00:22.733-05:00",
         "protectedVmCount":1
      },
      {
         "name":"job f",
         "instanceUid":"a4f5c4d8-c84b-4efd-91f0-cf8429604d6f",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-25T13:00:01.663-05:00",
         "protectedVmCount":1
      },
      {
         "name":"job g",
         "instanceUid":"9623dda4-8d8d-45b5-aa8a-b59feb828178",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T17:00:03.253-05:00",
         "protectedVmCount":1
      },
      {
         "name":"job f",
         "instanceUid":"8e8319d6-a03e-4926-969f-c38f060b2bb1",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T17:00:04.393-05:00",
         "protectedVmCount":1
      },
      {
         "name":"job g",
         "instanceUid":"79840a7e-b4b1-4284-ba20-de4eef1ada3f",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Failed",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T17:30:54.88-05:00",
         "protectedVmCount":1
      },
      {
         "name":"job h",
         "instanceUid":"32e5569f-3d7c-4bff-9fbf-cf00a9efddcf",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T17:00:03.643-05:00",
         "protectedVmCount":2
      },
      {
         "name":"job i",
         "instanceUid":"1230f103-38ce-405b-88c6-6f5c0cd62119",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Failed",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T17:30:54.893-05:00",
         "protectedVmCount":1
      },
      {
         "name":"job j",
         "instanceUid":"32e5569f-3d7c-4bff-9fbf-cf00a9efddcf",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T17:00:04.02-05:00"
      },
      {
         "name":"job k",
         "instanceUid":"1230f103-38ce-405b-88c6-6f5c0cd62119",
         "type":"BackupVm",
         "status":"Success",
         "lastRun":"2021-02-24T21:00:19.123-05:00"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Neither of the jsons are valid. Please try to provide valid samples.

Comment: You can use [this website](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to check validity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code, if you project allows you to create classes for the JSON you receives.

first created these classes

```
public class ORGType
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string instanceUid { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string lastRun { get; set; }
}

public class protectecVMS
{
    public string instanceUid { get; set; }
    public string protectedVmCount { get; set; }
}
```

then fetched JSON file content into their respective List type

```
string path = "./organtisationResponse.json";
string orgJSONFilecontent = File.ReadAllText(path);

var orgobjList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ORGType>>(orgJSONFilecontent);

path = "./protectedvms.json";
string protectedJsonFilecontent = File.ReadAllText(path);

var protectedobjList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<protectecVMS>>(protectedJsonFilecontent);
```

then performed a LINQ Join operation on both list based on `instanceUid`

```
// join to list based oninstance uid, 
var result = orgobjList.Join
    (
        protectedobjList,
        a => a.instanceUid,
        b => b.instanceUid,
        (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b })
    .Where(c => c.A.instanceUid == c.B.instanceUid)
    .Select(i => new { i.A.instanceUid, i.A.lastRun, i.A.name, i.A.status, i.A.type, i.B.protectedVmCount });

var resultJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

in order to check whether there exists any corresponding element in  `protectedObjList`, try this code.

```
result = from orgObj in orgobjList
         join protectedObj in protectedobjList on orgObj.instanceUid equals protectedObj.instanceUid into gj
         from subProtectedObj in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new
         {
             orgObj.instanceUid,
             orgObj.lastRun,
             orgObj.name,
             orgObj.status,
             orgObj.type,
             protectedVmCount = subProtectedObj?.protectedVmCount ?? string.Empty
         };
```

Comment: Thanks Paramjot!  That worked.   I was indeed trying to use first a union and then join in a different way but I would get protectedVMCount as null for the merged collection.   The only problem now I get is I want to get all of the collection from orgobjList regardless of whether or not there are corresponding values in protectedobjlist (like a left join).  How do I do that?